# Concatenação de Registros via FOR XML PATH - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014

Boa tarde prezados, estou com o seguinte problema:

Estou desenvolvendo uma Query onde preciso verificar quais documentos foram entregues pelo aluno, documentos estes que ficam na tabela pre_matricula_doc e possuí a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então o aluno de pré-matricula 2 apresentou os documentos 1 e 2, e o aluno de pré matrícula 3 apresentou o documento 3.

Dos documentos que foram apresentados pelo aluno "2" o 1 corresponde ao CPF, o 2 ao o RG, do aluno "3" trata-se da certidão de nascimento.

Estou trazendo estes documentos com a seguinte query:

```
SELECT      '; ' + DA.DESCRICAO
FROM        BD.pre_matricula_doc PDA
LEFT JOIN   BD.DOCUMENTOS DA ON PDA.pre_matricula   IN (1, 2)
                            AND DA.CODIGO           = PDA.documento 
                            AND PDA.apresentado     = '1'       
GROUP BY    PDA.pre_matricula
        ,   DA.descricao
```

A tabela PDA é a tabela onde ficam os documentos da pré matrícula (a qual coloquei a estrutura acima) e a tabela DA é onde está a descrição dos documentos (CPF, RG, Certidão de Nascimento).

Ocorre que, quando trago esta informação para apenas um aluno a query funciona corretamente, porém, quando menciono mais de um código na CLAUSULA IN a query concatena todos os documentos e trás para todos os alunos, vejam:

```
Aluno     Documentos apresentados

-----------------------------------

2         RG; CPF; Certidão de nascimento
3         RG; CPF; Certidão de nascimento
```

Quando o resultado desejado seria:

```
Aluno     Documentos apresentados

-----------------------------------

2         RG; CPF;
3         Certidão de nascimento;
```

O que posso fazer para trazer a informação correta?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua consulta está a colocar filtros diretamente no `LEFT JOIN` quando deveriam estar na cláusula `WHERE`:

```
SELECT      '; ' + DA.DESCRICAO
FROM        BD.pre_matricula_doc    PDA
LEFT JOIN   BD.DOCUMENTOS           DA  ON DA.CODIGO = PDA.documento
WHERE       PDA.pre_matricula   IN (2, 3)
        AND PDA.apresentado     = '1'
GROUP BY    PDA.pre_matricula
        ,   DA.descricao
```

Com o filtro `PDA.pre_matricula IN (1, 2)` apenas irá trazer aqueles com valor 1 ou 2 da coluna `pre_matricula` (erro de digitação?), daí ter alterado para `IN (2, 3)`, onde consegue obter informação para os valores 2 e 3.